Generate random value for pokemon(object) like strength then display that value in a textbox and have the option to add this pokemon to a listbox
I want to generate a pokemon with strength(random number 1-1000) and name(random name) in 2 textboxes and all while doing this making the pokemon into an object then i want the option to add the generated pokemon object to a listbox. I want to use 2 buttons one for generating objects the other for adding the generated pokemon to a listbox.
I have tried with various things like trying to call the button 2 method but gotten nowhere since it just wont accept the code im writing and could'nt find information on how you use 1 button to generate objects then add that generated object using another one. Please help this is just for fun.
This is what i tried.
namespace PokemonRNGG
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        List<Pokemon> pokemon = new List<Pokemon>();
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        class Pokemon
        {
            public int strength;
            public string name;

        }


        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Pokemon pkmn = new Pokemon();
            pkmn.strength = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            textbox1.Text = pkmn;
            

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(new Pokemon());
        }
    }
}


Clearly you need to store your new Pokemon object somewhere in a scope that both button1 and button2 can access. At the moment, pkmn is a local variable in the scope of the button1_Click method.

You have to solve your problem in 2 steps.

generate a pokemon on button click and store it somewhere

Take the stored Pokemon and add it to your list


First I added a variable randomizedPokemon which will hold the generated object. I declared it as nullable so it can also be null which is important if you only want to be able to add a pokemon after it was generated.
Second, I added a list of pokemonNames which will be used to create a pokemon.
What you also did wrong was assigning the object of pokemon directly to a listbox and / or textbox. Usually they only store string values. That's why you need to take the Name property from your class Pokemon and add it / assign it as a value. The code could look like the following.
Note that I do a null check before adding the instance of randomizedPokemon to our list because it might be null. After we added it, we set it back to null.
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Pokemon? randomizedPokemon = null;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<string> pokemonNames = new List<string> { "Pikachu", "Charizard" };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        randomizedPokemon = new Pokemon
        {
            Name = pokemonNames[rnd.Next(pokemonNames.Count)],
            Strength = rnd.Next(0, 100)
        };
        textbox1.Text = randomizedPokemon.Name;
    }
    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(randomizedPokemon != null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(randomizedPokemon.Name);

            randomizedPokemon = null;
        }
    }
}


class Pokemon
{
    public int Strength { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

